# Hibernate JPA recursive query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, recursion

I have the following query, I'm using hibernate a JPA provider:

```
entityManager().createQuery(
            "SELECT page FROM ProjectPage page"
             +" left join fetch page.categorySet as category"
             + " where page.id = :id " 
             + " and  category.parentCategory is null "
             + " and  (category.status is null or category.status != :status_val) "
            ,ProjectPage.class).setParameter("id", id).setParameter("status_val", Status.DELETED).getSingleResult();
```

and below are the entities of `ProjectPage` and `Category` respectively:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project_page")
@Configurable
public class ProjectPage {

@OneToMany( mappedBy = "parentPage")
private Set<Category> categorySet = new HashSet<Category>();
}


@Configurable
@Table(name="category")
@Entity
public class Category{

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parentCategory",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private Set<com.se.dataadminbl.model.Category> categorySet = new HashSet<com.se.dataadminbl.model.Category>();

}
```

in the above query, i'm trying to fetch a `ProjectPage` along with its `categorySet` and as shown above class `Category` contains a set of its type, so every `ProjectPage` object will contain a set of `Category` and each object inside this set will contains a set of `Category`, now the problem is that when i retrieve the `ProjectPage` object the conditions in the where clause applied only on the first level set of `Category` not on each set inside each `Category`, i want to make a recursive query so that i can apply the where condition to the nth level instead of doing that with code, i tried to use interceptor but doesn't work, any idea of how to do that?

Comment: Do you expect that enforcing a `WHERE` condition on a collection in a `OneToMany` relationship would allow you to access filtered rows (according to the condition) from that collection - in your case, `categorySet` (`Set<Category>`) through the parent entity `page`? No, it would not happen. So, please try changing the approach. Please do not also use aliasing with `JOIN FETCH` in a `OneToMany` relationship (though it is supported by some JPA providers) to filter rows (to navigate through the target entity (the one which has the foreign key)) that would otherwise alter how the objects are built

Answer (score 0):

1. The WHERE condition will always filter out nulls when you reference a LEFT JOIN column in your WHERE clause. So the end result is an INNER JOIN.
2. Neither JPA nor Hibernate support recursive queries, because [there's no one and only one standard implementation amongst all databases Hibernate supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL).
3. In case you use PostgreSQL, you can use a [Common Table Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html).